# User Privileges for OPTIMIZE TABLE

Tags: mysql, optimization, privileges

I was reading on Stackoverflow that in order to clear `overhead` on a `MyISAM` table, you need to run [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html), within the MySQL reference document it notes..

> Note that MySQL locks the table during the time OPTIMIZE TABLE is running.

I was wondering is the `LOCK TABLES` `Privilege` necessary for `OPTIMIZE TABLE`? if so why?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need that privilege.

*This statement requires SELECT and INSERT privileges for the table.*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer your particular question, but to point out related info...

But...  `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, even for MyISAM tables, is rarely needed.  I have researched thousands of slow queries/tables, and have seen only two cases where `OPTIMIZE TABLE` was "the answer".  And, after digging deeper, I deduced that "once a month" was sufficient for both of those cases.  Don't waste your time with frequent, widespread, `OPTIMIZEs`.

That statement will block all writes to the table.  And, in doing so, it may also block reads.  So, be careful when you do it.